# MVC 3 & Razor with legacy database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a small to medium sized project to work on and I wanted to use the new MVC 3 and Razor but unfortunately I will need to hit a mssql 2000 as well as an ms FoxPro 8 database.

Maybe I am stuck using ADO.Net typed data sets and webforms? Whats the best/easiest way to get type data sets into List or even just make them enumerable so I can use foreach etc for output?

Would it be better to map each data set row to a POCO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datastore you are using has nothing to do with the frontend application. You could perfectly fine use ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor as frontend and abstract the data access layer in a repository. In the implementation of this repository you could use ADO.NET with data readers that return strongly typed model objects, Forget about the legacy DataSets. You could use an ORM such as NHibernate to simplify the conversion between SQL queries and objects. As far as MVC views are concerned you should use view models which are specific to each view instead of your model objects coming from the repository. To map between different object types you may take a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET DataReaders are much faster than Data Sets. Then inside the DataReader, load to POCO. You could also map DataSet rows to POCO (as you mention).

Is there a reason you can't use Entity Framework?

Comment: Prior to EF 4 I tried using EF against one of our FoxPro db but the tooling would not support it. That may not be the case with 4.0 as I have not tried it that I can remember.

Comment: You can use EF without the tooling, though at that point DataReaders may become easier to use. Darin is also correct in pointing out that your choice of web framework shouldn't correlate to your choice of DAL technology.